# How to hide Home link in SharePoint 2016 global navigation

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2016, css, global-navigation

There is a "Home" link in global navigation of my publishing site which I want to hide. It is not available in "Navigation" in "Site Settings" so I cannot hide it from there.

All the solutions available on internet are about SharePoint 2010/2013 and they are not working for SharePoint 2016. How can I hide that Home link?

**EDIT**

Here's that element:

```
<a class="static selected menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-core-listMenu-selected ms-navedit-linkNode shortpoint-nav-home-link shortpoint-nav-a-selected" accesskey="1" href="/sites/somesite/en/Pages/default.aspx">
    <span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow">
        <span class="menu-item-text" data-original-word="English">Home</span>
        <span class="ms-hidden">Currently selected</span>
    </span>
</a>
```

Comment: Are you not able to hide the link using custom css and element selector (of home link)?

Comment: That's what I am trying to do but I am unable to find unique element selector using which I can hide the home link.

Comment: try something like `a[title^='Home'][class^='ms-Nav-link']`

Comment: I have mentioned element in my original post. Please check.

Comment: Try using `a.menu-item.shortpoint-nav-home-link {display: none !important}`. let me know if this works

Comment: Not working. I have defined it just before `</head>` in Master page. Screenshot https://i.imgur.com/GtVrabw.jpg

Comment: Is it accepted to use JS/Jquery to hide the element?

Comment: Yes JS/Jquery will be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I add below style in a [Altertive CSS](https://donnasresources.com/branding-your-sharepoint-site-with-an-alternate-style-sheet/) file and it works well here.

```
a.menu-item.shortpoint-nav-home-link {
    display: none !important
}

div#sideNavBox li.static:first-child{
    display: none !important
}
```

[image]

Below is my page element:

[image]

And you may have a try JS code:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("div#sideNavBox span:contains('Home')").closest("li").hide();
 
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint 2016 and 2019, the best working option to remove the site collection title from the top global navigation, without changing the master page, consists in adding to the page this in a script editor web part:

```
<style type="text/css">
#DeltaTopNavigation ul.ms-core-listMenu-root > li:first-child > a
{
    display: none !important; 
}
</style>
```

This leave the "Home" in left navigation menu, but remove the site collection title from the top menu.

If you want instead to remove from both (left and top menu) use the following:

```
<style type="text/css">
ul.ms-core-listMenu-root > li:first-child > a
{
    display: none !important; 
}
</style>
```